# Images dont load anymore after uploading to webserver

Tags: html, image, path, webserver

I uploaded the site to a webserver but now the images are not loading, i think its something with the path but I cant figure out whats wrong about it. 
http://wilpegroup.webshoptool.nl/

Comment: What kind of server are you using? What's the folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img alt="logo van curolcock" src="img/logo/wilpe_beeldmerk.svg">`

The above location http://wilpegroup.webshoptool.nl/img/logo does not exist.  You need to create the logo folder in the img directory then upload the SVG file.

This will need to be done for all broken images, changing file paths to match the code.

Comment: If this fixed, please mark as answer so others looking for similar issues can get the right answer.  Thanks

Comment: i will but have to wait 5 minutes before i can accept answer